# headsets mic not recognized

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headset

I have a headset, which is recognized as sound output only. The mic isn't recognized, even not by `alsamixer`(v1.1.3). (As input I only see: `Mic Boost`, `Capture` and `Digital`.)

In my previous linux install, I could fix this by adding the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

but now that file looks totally different and I run in trubble when I tried to add that file. (I had to reboot, and sound stopped working, I removed the line and rebooted again and it restarted working.)

Please note:

- I don't have exactly the mentioned mic, it was just a crappy workaround
- system doesn't recognize the mic, neither in alsamixer nor in pavucontrol I can select it
- I have XUbuntu 18.04

What additional information do you need? I will add it.